# "! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end." with the \boxput* function

Tags: line-breaking, fancybox

I am trying to put some boxes on the second with the paquage

```
\usepackage{fancybox}
```

My code looks like that

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancybox,color}

\begin{document}

\boxput*(-0.4,1.1){    
 \textbf{MathBox : }Akaike information criterion    }{
        \colorbox{blue}{
        \ovalbox{
    \begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}    
     \newline   
    Text    
    $eqation$    
    Text
\footnote{\textit{Everitt (1998), The Cambridge Dictionary of Statistics }}
    \end{minipage}  
    }}}

\end{document}
```

I use this type of boxing three time, and it made me an error on two of them at the end of the boxing.
I do not have any `\\` in the boxes or next before. 
The strangest is that the code finish to compile and the box appear in the pdf. I compile with pdflatex in TexMaker (on ubuntu)

I really do not know what is the problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error comes from the `\newline` which you have immediately at the start of the `minipage` You can not end the current line and start a new line until you have started the paragraph, hence the error. Simply deleting the `\newline` makes the error go.

Comment: And if you cannot remove that newline, because your whole file is one big hack: adding a whitespace `~` before the newline should work as well

Comment: @lucidbrot but that's probably worse than simply ignoring the error. As you get bad output with no warning.

Comment: how is the output bad though? It looks well. Thanks for speaking up: I have now tried some variation of my hack which allows me to remove the whitespace and the newline (which was in fact a negative vertical offset). That gives much cleaner code.

Comment: Thanks! Page breaking is a good argument. (I only had the box in order to be able to move its whole content, so breaking alignment is fine by me)

Comment: @lucidbrot Oh OK I was just going to point out that you could ask the staff to merge the accounts if you were (I'm going to delete most of these comments in a minute)